Why doesn't NavigationSplitView update value when navigating to same View in details?
I have a NavigationSplitView and router for navigation with code.
Of some reason, it works only when I change the views.
Changing ViewB from 42 to 100 works when changing via ViewA.
But, changing ViewB to ViewB (40 to 100) doesn't work (actually, it works on iPhone).
I have also tried to use Text with .tag.
Is there anything in navigation that I miss?

import SwiftUI
import Observation


enum NavigationRoute: Hashable {
    case viewA(title: String)
    case viewB(count: Int)
}

@Observable
class AppState {
    var selectedRoute: NavigationRoute?

    func navigateTo(route : NavigationRoute){
        selectedRoute = route
    }
}


// ViewModels
@Observable
class ViewAViewModel {
    var title: String
    
    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

@Observable
class ViewBViewModel {
    var count: Int
    
    init(count: Int) {
        self.count = count
    }
}

// Views
struct ViewA: View {
    @State var viewModel: ViewAViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("View A: \(viewModel.title)")
            .frame(width: 400, height: 100)
            .background(.orange)
    }
}

struct ViewB: View {
    @State var viewModel: ViewBViewModel
    var body: some View {
        Text("View B: Count is \(viewModel.count)")
            .frame(width: 400, height: 100)
            .background(.blue)
    }
}

@Observable
class MainViewSidebarViewModel {
    var appState: AppState
    
    init(appState: AppState) {
        self.appState = appState
    }
        
    func navigateTo(route : NavigationRoute){
        appState.navigateTo(route: route)
    }
}


struct MainViewSidebarView: View {
    @Bindable var viewModel: MainViewSidebarViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section("Section A") {
                Button("View A row 1") {
                    viewModel.navigateTo(route: .viewA(title: "View A row 1"))
                }
                Button("View A row 2") {
                    viewModel.navigateTo(route: .viewA(title: "View A row 2"))
                }
            }
            Section("Section B") {
                Button("View B: 42") {
                    viewModel.navigateTo(route: .viewB(count: 42))
                }
                Button("View B: 100") {
                    viewModel.navigateTo(route: .viewB(count: 100))
                }
            }
            
            Text("Settings")
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
        .navigationTitle("Sidebar")
    }
}

@Observable
class MainViewDetailsViewModel {
    
    var appState: AppState

    init(appState: AppState) {
        self.appState = appState
    }
}

struct MainViewDetailsView: View {
    @Bindable var viewModel: MainViewDetailsViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        switch viewModel.appState.selectedRoute {
        case .viewA(let title):
            ViewA(viewModel: ViewAViewModel(title: title))
        case .viewB(let count):
            ViewB(viewModel: ViewBViewModel(count: count))
        case .none:
            Text("Select a view")
        }
    }
}

@Observable
class MainViewModel {
    var appState : AppState
    var vmSidebar: MainViewSidebarViewModel
    var vmDetails: MainViewDetailsViewModel
    
    init() {
        let appStateTmp = AppState()
        appState = appStateTmp
        vmSidebar = MainViewSidebarViewModel(appState: appStateTmp)
        vmDetails = MainViewDetailsViewModel(appState: appStateTmp)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    @Bindable private var vm = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            MainViewSidebarView(viewModel: vm.vmSidebar)
        } detail: {
            MainViewDetailsView(viewModel: vm.vmDetails)
        }
        .navigationSplitViewStyle(.balanced)

    }
}

// MARK: - App Entry Point

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


State should always be private use Bindable or let

In SwiftUI the View struct is the view model already you don't need your own objects. It will automatically generate the real view layer based on your structs.

You have thing back to front, you should declare @State private var vm = MainViewModel() in ContentView
and same for all your models eg ViewAViewModel etc... so the View can observe/manage them.
That is, do not use ViewA(viewModel: ViewAViewModel(title: title)), declare the model with @State... so the View  can manage it. Conversely, you should have let viewModel: ViewAViewModel or  @Bindable var ... for those in your subviews. See Managing data it gives some good simple practical examples.

thank you, got it working with
@Bindable var viewModel: ViewBViewModel

init(initCnt: Int) {
    self.viewModel = ViewBViewModel(count: initCnt)
}

I will accept it as an answer if you post it.
